# AngularJS + Jade ng-repeat does not fill the table

Tags: angularjs, pug

I am trying to fill a table via AngularJS.
My controller receives through a socket data.

The data looks like:

```
[{score: 2, team: 1, kills: 9, assists: 2, deaths: 0}, {score: 2, team: 1, kills: 9, assists: 2, deaths: 0}]
```

I tried to reduce the code to the relevant stuff, but maybe I did something wrong by that, but the jade templates renderes usually.

index.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang='en', ng-app="app")
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    title= title
    // Bootstrap CSS
    link(href='stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
    // Socket
    script(src='https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js')
    // jQuery
    script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js')
    // Angular
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js')
    script(src='javascripts/controller.js')
    // Main CSS
    link(href='stylesheets/main.css', rel='stylesheet')
  body(ng-controller="controller")
    .content.row
      .col-md-12.data
        .table-responsive
          table.table.table-hover
            thead
              tr
                th Score
                th Kills
                th Assists
                th Deaths
            tbody
              tr(ng-repeat="1 in data")
                td {{1.score}}
                td {{1.kills}}
                td {{1.assists}}
                td {{1.deaths}}
    script(src='javascripts/bootstrap.min.js')
```

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
    var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

My controller receives the data and when I do `console.log($scope.data)` it returns me my sent data.
The problems must be somewhere in the jade template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `$scope.$apply()` after assigning data in `socket.on('data'` event. Because udpating scope variable through an events will not run digest cycle. you need to run it manually by call `$apply()` on `$scope` or either you could wrap function inside `$scope.$apply(function(){ //do scope variable updation from here })`

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
    var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Now I run into another problem. `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=1%20in%20data&p1=string%3A%20&p2=%20`

Comment: for that you should use `track by $index` on your `ng-repeat` like `tr(ng-repeat="1 in data track by $index")`

Comment: My table now has like 150 rows. The data is only received once and 10 indexes long

Comment: yes i did. I added track by $index. But it does way more entries in the table then indexes exist

Comment: My data array has 10 items/objects, whatever. When I now send the data to the client and apply it, my table has like 100 rows and not 10